# An exception occurred while trying to update the data smart tasks, they will be disabled. Requested value 'Properties' was not found

Tags: c#, exception, runtime-error

When I open any window in project in Visual Studio, I get this error message. I did not find any results. What is the reason?

**An exception occurred while trying to update the data smart tasks, they will be disabled. Requested value 'Properties' was not found.**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLYSC.png)